# Add or subtract number with index jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this poorly written code to add or subtract a number within the html.

The output will look like this on the first index:

1/ 6

On the last index it will look like this:

6/ 6

This is used together with pageslide.js. This is my alternative to the built in pagination system.
Is there anyway to write this smarter?

```
    if(index == '1'){
        $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text("1/ ");
    }

    if(index == '2'){
        $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text("2/ ");
    }

    if(index == '3'){
        $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text("3/ ");
    }

    if(index == '4'){
        $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text("4/ ");
    }

    if(index == '5'){
        $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text("5/ ");
    }

    if(index == '6'){
        $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text("6/ ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need filtering or checking of the value go for:

```
$( ".sectionCurrent" ).text(index + "/ ");
```

If the value needs to be between 1/6:

```
if(index > 0 && < 7){
   $( ".sectionCurrent" ).text(index + "/ ");
}
```